# Exporting doc types using queues and multithreading

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

For a while I have been interested in seeing if some tasks work well when split across multiple threads.

On the one project I have been busy with I have been creating a lot of small utility apps, to do single tasks for me, so this morning while modifying one I thought I would give it a try.

What I wrote seems to work, although I am not sure if it is the best way, or recommended way to do something like this, so I want to ask what is wrong with my code and how could it be done better. What it is doing is not really important, and I am not interested if this sort of task should be split up, but more along the lines of how good or bad is the code that I have written.

```
private static void ExportDocTypes(IEnumerable<string> docTypes)
{
    var queue = new Queue<string>(docTypes);
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    for (byte i = 0; i < threadCount; i++)  //threadCount is a const set to 4.
    {
        Action a = () =>
        {
            while(queue.Count() > 0) {
                var type = queue.Dequeue();
                ExportDocuments(type, i);  //i is only sent for response.write
            }
        };
        var t = new Task(a);
        t.Start();
        tasks.Add(t);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
    }
    while (tasks.Count() > 0)
    {
        foreach (var t in tasks)
        {
            if (t.IsCompleted)
            {
                t.Dispose();
                tasks.Remove(t);
            }
        }
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does that code even work? I'd expect it to crash if two tasks complete withing the same second.

Comment: It actually does. It is very unlikly that two would ever end at the same time, but I still don't see how that would be an issue.
The Sleep(10) was so that two tasks didn't try grab the same docType at the same time.

Comment: When you remove t from tasks, the size of tasks changes, which invalidates the foreach loop.  Imagine it was a for loop, you would iterate outside the bounds of the list once it shrinks.  You could `break` from the foreach loop, but `Task.WaitAll()` or even linq `.All(t => t.IsCompleted)` would be more elegant.

Comment: That is a very good point, I didn't even notice that.

Comment: @JonathanPeel "very unlikely" things happen all the time when you're doing multithreaded programming. You're just asking for intermitttent, hard-to-reproduce bugs.

Comment: In my experience, "very unlikely" means "guaranteed to happen at the worst possible time," where "worst possible" implies either an inability to reproduce it, or in front of an important customer.

Comment: I actually use multi-threading all the time (even an array of threads) the think you need to remember is that you have to keep it clean. Create your workers as separate classes; provide communication; clean-up after they are done. I also created a short (about 20 min) three part video tutorial (it is in VB but the general flow can be applied to C# as well). If you're interested here is a link:[.Net Multi-Threading Video Tutorial (Playlist)](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL-oJWlyYHTHn3i1iy8i3Sfvzlsha4Jdnk)

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Rather than reviewing your specific code -- which at first glance seems very, very buggy -- let me answer your question directly:

> What are the best practices with multithreading in C#?

1. Don't. Multithreading is a bad idea. Programs are hard enough to understand already with a *single* point of control flow in them; why on earth would you want to add a second, third, fourth... ? Do you enjoy tracking down incredibly difficult-to-reproduce, impossible-to-understand bugs? Do you have an encyclopaedic knowledge of the differences between weak and strong memory models? No?  Then don't write multithreaded programs!  Processes are a perfectly good unit of work; if you have work to do, spawn a process.
2. Oh, so you want to do multithreaded programming anyways.  In that case **use the highest level of abstraction available**.  Programming against threads directly means writing programs about *workers* when you could be writing programs about *jobs*. Remember, workers are just means to an end; what you really want to get done are the jobs.  Use the **[Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)**: tasks are *jobs*, threads are *workers*. Let the TPL figure out for you how to make efficient use of workers.
3. Wait, let's go back to point one again.  Ask yourself **do you really need concurrency?** With true concurrency we have two or more points of control in a program *actually active at the same time*. With simulated concurrency the two points of control take turns using the processor, so they are not actually concurrent. Most of the time we end up with simulated concurrency, because there are more threads than there are processors. This leads us naturally to the conclusion that perhaps actual concurrency is not what we need. Much of the time what people really want is *asynchrony*; concurrency is one way to achieve asynchrony, but it is not the only way.  **Use the new [async/await functionality in C# 5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx)** to represent asynchronous workflows.
4. If you are confused by the previous point, and think wait a minute, there is no way to achieve asynchrony without multiple threads of control in a process, read Stephen Cleary's article **[There Is No Thread](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html)**.  Don't try to write multithreaded programs until you understand it.
5. At all costs **avoid shared memory**. Most threading bugs are caused by a failure to understand real-world shared memory semantics. If you must make threads, treat them as though they were processes: give them everything they need to do their work and let them work *without* modifying the memory associated with any other thread. Just like a process doesn't get to modify the memory of any other process.
6. Oh, so you want to share memory across threads even though doing so is incredibly bug prone? Again, let me go back to **use the highest level tool available to you**. Those tools were written by experts. You're not an expert. Do you know how to make a lazily-computed value written to a field such that you are *absolutely guaranteed* that the lazy computation executes no more than once and the field is never observed to be in an inconsistent state no matter what is in any given processor cache?  I don't. You probably don't. Joe Duffy does, which is why you should use the [`Lazy<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) primitive he wrote rather than trying to write your own.
7. Oh, so you want to write your own code that shares memory? Then **take the lock** for heaven's sake. I see so much buggy code where people get into their heads that locks are expensive and they write this convoluted godawful wrong code that evades taking a lock that would have cost them **twelve nanoseconds** to just take. Avoiding a lock to save on its cost is like complaining that the electricity takes too long to get to the light bulb when you flip the switch. Locks are a powerful tool for ensuring memory consistency; if you're going to program shared memory at the thread level, you avoid locks at your peril.
8. If you use `Thread.Sleep` with an argument other than zero or one in any production code, you are possibly doing something wrong. Threads are expensive; you don't pay a worker to sleep, so don't pay a thread to sleep either. If you are using sleeps to solve a correctness issue by avoiding a timing problem -- as you appear to be in your code -- then you definitely have done something deeply wrong. **Multithreaded code needs to be correct irrespective of accidents of timing**.

Comment: If you use Thread.Sleep with the argument zero, that feels wrong too...

Comment: I'm with you ...until #8. For example, I have a piece of code in front of me that sends out a request (through UDP) on a thread every ~400ms, waits for a response, and if it gets a valid response it updates a shared list (locking it). `Thread.Sleep(400);` seems perfectly fine in the loop.

Comment: @Blindy In Java, there's `ScheduledExecutorService` for that, I'm sure C# has something similar.

Comment: Eric: You say "an argument other than zero or one", when/why would `Thread.Sleep(1)` be OK?

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg, I guess I could use a threaded timer, but why go through all the trouble of maintaining out-of-scope sockets and other misc objects (decoders, validators) and managing their lifetime (especially the socket) when a `while(1)` loop does exactly what I need?

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg: Sleep(0) has a very specific meaning; it means "relinquish control to any thread of equal priority that is ready to run; if no such thread exists, do not relinquish control".  Sleep(1) means "relinquish control". This subtle difference sometimes matters.

Comment: @Blindy: Suppose instead you did not spawn a dedicated thread and used `await Task.Delay(400)` instead. **Now the current thread can keep doing work while time passes instead of sitting there asleep**.

Comment: Sure, but there's nothing else that thread has to do. That was kind of the idea, the thread will be asleep most of the time, either a hard sleep or waiting on socket I/O, while the rest of my program does its thing. It's the producer part of a producer-consumer-UI trifecta. I'm not saying using `Sleep` is a good idea in general, especially not as synchronization, but there are use cases for it IMO

Comment: @Blindy: That's a good point. By dedicating the thread to do one logical job, by specifying that it communicates with other threads by clearly-defined mechanisms, and by restricting how much it touches shared memory to a specific, thread-safe object, you are really treating the thread as a lightweight process, which is a good practice. In a world without async/await, that's how I likely would have done it too. I'll soften my advice somewhat.

Comment: @Blindy: Doing something "every ~400 milliseconds" is why timers exist.  You don't need to dedicate a thread to it, and a timer's more likely to get the timing right in cases where that matters.  Unless you're carefully watching the time, you're running every (400ms + however long it took to send and receive last time).

Comment: http://thecodelesscode.com/case/121

Comment: @cHao, precision doesn't matter, and it has to be off the UI thread anyway (or it has to use the Task API, which I didn't have access to back then).

Comment: @Blindy: [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) has been around since 1.1.

Comment: @EricLippert, thank you for your answer and reading sources.
Most of the time I stay away from things like this, but every now and then when I am writing a small once off app, that will only ever be seen me, and only ever run by me I try to do things a little differently to how I normally do, or use the time to try and learn something, that is why the question.
I have used async/await. It makes sense to me in apps with a UI where I want to keep the interface responsive, but on programs that aren't interactive, if I am going to await something, I may as well just do it in the same thread.

Comment: @Blindy "but there's nothing else that thread has to do" actually there is almost nothing that the thread IS doing. Most of its life is spent waiting for an I/O process. Even using `Task.Run` instead makes more sense, since you use the ThreadPool then.

Comment: "*Logical* processes are a perfectly good unit of work". Yes, they are. Unfortuantely, the actual OS-provided implementations of the "process" concept are rather heavy-weight, even on Linux. So people emulate it with threads: "one thread for one logical process". But even this is not perfect, so people do thread pools, and fibers, and UMS, and all other exciting techniques that make stack traces ultimately useless.

Comment: @EricLippert After Windows XP, the [Windows API's `Sleep` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) was changed to mean "A value of zero causes the thread to relinquish the remainder of its time slice to any other thread that is ready to run", regardless of the other thread's priority.

Comment: I don't think `Sleep(1)` is useful anymore.

Comment: @dcastro: Technically, C# is not Microsoft-specific.

Comment: @Brian True, but Eric and I were referring to the Windows API's (past) behaviour, which is Microsoft-specific.

Comment: Head's up to everyone. This post has been auto-flagged for having too many comments (so I am going to add another one). Comments are not intended to be a tool for conversations. How about heading off to [The 2nd monitor chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) for further dialog.

Comment: @EricLippert Is it really *never* worth multi-threading? For example, I use it very effectively in my current C# project in processing unrelated items in a `List<string[]>`. Just hand the function that data type and it flies through hundreds of thousands of elements, and I've never had a problem with it. I agree that superfluous use of threads is dangerous and unnecessary. Won't go into a long discussion about it, I'm just sure that there are very valid uses (like when item order of processing/time of completion is unimportant - background tasks that don't affect other logic). +1 in any case!

Comment: +1 for "Don't"  I have worked on too many systems that had lots of problems due to multthreading that was not needed.

Comment: Stephen Cleary's article is very informative, but does not seem particularly relevant to the C# `async` and `await` keywords, especially if you're not involving the operating system in your `async` operation.  Device drivers and hardware interfaces have little to do with the way `async` and `await` works.

Answer (score 17):

You can use `Parallel` class:

```
private static void ExportDocTypes(IEnumerable<string> docTypes)
{
    int i = -1;
    Parallel.ForEach(docTypes, docType => ExportDocuments(docType, Interlocked.Increment(ref i)));
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I have not seen the Parallel class before, but that does look useful. The list of doxType could have 100 or maybe 1000 items. Would these all run together, or does it handle a thread limit automatically?

Comment: By default it tries to calculate the optimal number of threads (usually it's a number of cores your CPU has). You can, however, set this number manually. Check the overloaded method which takes `ParallelOptions` class as a parameter.

Comment: That is pretty cool, I like the idea of it being able to determine what the best is (I am pretty sure it will do a better job than I will).
I will give it a try.

Do you think this is better than the other method?
It is less code, possibly neater code, other than that does it have other advantages?

Comment: You can use Reflector or some other utility to check the actual implementation, but i am pretty sure that it is going to be quite similar to what you are trying to do: with tasks, thread pool and stuff. And with no "magic". Now, if you can come up with better implementation than microsoft or not - that is not for me to judge. :) You may certainly try.

Comment: could you please explain to me what `Interlocked.Increment` is for, and why is is used and not just `++i`?

Comment: @JonathanPeel, regular increment is not thread-safe. To perform it, you should first read the variable from memory, then add 1, then write new value back. If another thread modifies this variable during any of those steps you will get an incorrect result (for example, two increments performed at roughly the same time on different threads may result in overall `+1` and not `+2`). `Interlocked` class provides atomic (= performed using single step) versions of some simple operations, making those operations thread-safe.

Comment: But what I was looking was for a different "copy" of the variable to go to method each time.
Because (as far as I understand) integers are always passed as values as not references `++i` should increment the counter, then pass that thread it's own copy of it. because it gets it's own copy/value it shouldn't need to be thread safe.

I might be wrong on this.

I have taken that out all together, because it is actually not needed, but it is still interesting to see how things should be done.

Comment: I have had another look.

If everything after `docType =>` is happening in it's own process then the increment would be happening in the to the same value from different places.

Comment: @JonathanPeel, by default value types are passed by _value_, yes. You have a different case, however. You do not "pass" `i` anywhere. You use a variable from outer scope in the inner scope of anonymous delegate, which will then be accessed by _reference_. This is something known as "closure", which might be confusing at first/ You can read more here: http://diditwith.net/PermaLink,guid,235646ae-3476-4893-899d-105e4d48c25b.aspx

Answer (score 11):

I would do something like this:

```
private static void ExportDocTypes(IEnumerable<string> docTypes)
{
    var queue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>(docTypes);
    var tasks = new List<Task>();

    for (byte i = 0; i < threadCount; i++)  //threadCount is a const set to 4.
    {
        byte iteration = i;
        Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            string type;
            bool queueNotEmpty = queue.TryDequeue(out type);
            while(queueNotEmpty) 
            {
                ExportDocuments(type, iteration);  //i is only sent for response.write
                bool queueEmpty = queue.TryDequeue(out type);
            }
        });
        tasks.Add(t);
    }

    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
    tasks.ForEach(task => task.Dispose());
}
```

Making use of things like `ConcurrentQueue` as many threads will be simultaneously accessing it. Also making greater use of Linq and static methods on Task to check for completion instead of using Thread.Sleep.

Edit: Also, totally missed this previously, you need to make a local copy of `i` within the for loop, otherwise `i` will point to the current value, instead of the captured value at that iteration. Something to be aware of while spawning Tasks in loops.

Comment: Thank you
would `while(queue.TryDequeue(out type))` work, is there a reason for not doing that?

Comment: That would indeed be an improvement.  I only wrote it that way for clarity.

Comment: I noticed the iteration issue as well. Thank you.

Comment: That variable isn't needed at all, I was response.writing it just for my own interest.

Comment: I see no reason to use queue here. You can simply iterate through `docTypes` in `foreach` loop.

Comment: You are correct.  The above code is based on the assumption that there should only be `threadCount` number of concurrent tasks.  Otherwise, I would agree with your `Parallel.ForEach` method, which ought to perform significantly faster.