# Chaining asynchronous tasks that must run sequentially

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I want to implement an [`Agent`-like](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/agents.html) object in C#. An Agent wraps some memory location (ideally storing an immutable object) and receives updates to that location. All these updates are performed asynchronously, but sequentially. In other words

> At any point in time, at most one [update submitted to an] Agent is
>   being executed.

My current implementation uses the TPL. The `Agent` keeps a reference to the last update that has been or must be performed, wrapped in a `Task`. When submitted a new update, you wrap the update in a `Task`, get a reference to the last `Task` and replace it, atomically, then invoke `ContinueWith` on that last `Task` with this new update `Task` (everything submitted through a `TaskScheduler`).

```
public class Agent<T> where T : class
{
    private T wrappedValue;
    private readonly TaskScheduler scheduler;
    private Task lastTask;

    public Agent (T value, TaskScheduler scheduler)
    {
        this.wrappedValue = value;
        this.scheduler = scheduler;
    }

    public void Send (Action<T> operation)
    {
        Task task = new Task ((action) => ((Action<T>)action) (wrappedValue), operation);
        Task localCurrent;
        do {
            // always append to the end
            localCurrent = lastTask;
        } while(Interlocked.CompareExchange (ref lastTask, task, localCurrent) != localCurrent);

        if (localCurrent == null) {
            task.Start (scheduler);
        } else {
            localCurrent.ContinueWith ((currentTask, scheduler) => {
                task.Start ((TaskScheduler)scheduler);
            }, scheduler, scheduler);
        }
    }
    [...]
}
```

The first thread to send an action will see `null` in the field and so needs to `Start()` the `Task` directly.

This (seems to) work. Only one submitted action is ever running at a given moment. Additionally, tasks are potentially run on different threads. I don't want a dedicated thread for updates (and I don't want to lock up a `TaskScheduler` thread).

However, I'm worried about a few things that I think could be improved:

- I'd like to be able to `ContinueWith` the `Task task` directly, instead of having to start it within a different submitted `Action`. I feel like I need to create the new `Task` so that I can atomically exchange the `lastTask` field's value.
- Lambda capturing of local variables, partly alleviated with state objects where possible.
- How can I keep a reference to the currently executing `Task`, so I can short-circuit execution? Or should I use a poison pill to signal termination and not chain any new tasks?
- `Interlocked` for atomicity. Should I use a `ConcurrentQueue`? How would I manage not having a dedicated thread and only running one `Task` at a time with a `ConcurrentQueue`?
- Is a `Volatile.Read` of `lastTask` necessary for `localCurrent = lastTask;`?

---

Doing this now

```
private void InvokeAndComplete (Action<T> act, TaskCompletionSource<byte> promise)
{
    try {
        act (internalValue);
    } finally {
        // some value we will ignore
        promise.SetResult (1);
    }
}

public Task Alter (Action<T> alterAction)
{
    TaskCompletionSource<byte> promise = new TaskCompletionSource<byte> ();
    Task localLastTask;
    do {
        // Not sure if Volatile.Read is necessary
        localLastTask = Volatile.Read (ref lastTask);
    } while (Interlocked.CompareExchange (ref lastTask, promise.Task, localLastTask) != localLastTask);
    // only this thread has a reference to the object referenced by localLastTask
    return localLastTask.ContinueWith ((currentTask) => {
        InvokeAndComplete (alterAction, promise);
    }, taskScheduler);
}
```

Comment: Check out [Reactive Extensions - a library for composing asynchronous and event-based programs using observable sequences and LINQ-style query operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577611.aspx)

Comment: @radarbob For chaining the tasks or for replacing the `Agent`?

Answer (score 3):

- I would use `lock` instead of `Interlocked`, because its much easier to follow and debug. Unless you are after some kind of micro optimization, I think you should keep it simple:

  ```
  lock (lock)
  {
      if (lastTask == null)
      {
         task.Start(scheduler);
      } 
      else 
      {
          lastTask.ContinueWith(...);
      }
      lastTask = task;
  }
  ```
- I think you can modify your lambda expression to get a current task:

  ```
  Task task = null;
  task = new Task ((action) => 
       {
           CurrentTask = task;
           ((Action<T>)action) (wrappedValue);
       }, operation);
  ```

  Though I am not too experienced with TPL, so there might be an easier way.

Comment: I'd rather not `lock` when the critical section takes less time that the locking itself. Maybe with a `SpinLock`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis have you read [this post from Eric Lippert](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/55335/23788)? The part about *locks being expensive* seems relevant - but don't get me wrong, this MT stuff is way over my head.

Comment: @Mat'sMug That is quite entertaining and useful, but I think I can hold my own in a multithreaded environment (though more in Java than C#). I'll admit that I have written the code with `lock` and it works, but I want to push the limits with `Interlocked`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, well if you *really need* to push the limits - by all means. But if there is no actual performance issue you are facing, then I would call this kind of micro-optimization an anti-pattern. Similar to how some people use shift operator to multiply, because multiplication is just not fast enough. :) But then again, its up to you.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use an `ActionBlock` with a `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` of 1?

```
private readonly ActionBlock<Action<T>> block = 
   new ActionBlock<Action<T>>(action => action(wrappedValue), 
                              new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions 
                                  { 
                                      MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1 
                                  });

public void Send (Action<T> operation)
{
    block.Post(operation);
}
```

Why? The best code is code you don't need to write, and this is almost a single-line solution. You won't need to concern yourself with housekeeping and synchronization and it accomplishes the primary requirement perfectly; it will execute your operations sequentially and asynchronously.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your post. *Why* should the user do this? *Why* is this solution better? Etc, etc. Just posting code and a small comment doesn't help the readers.

Comment: This simplifies the code. It's good to know, but it slows things down. I want to use lower level primitives if possible.